# ORA-00904 invalid identifier error in dynamic SQL block

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm running the below which once executed, an error is reported telling me that EST_ONE_ROW_MB is an invalid identifier.

I've been advised I perhaps need to get the dynamic SQL part running as a stand alone query to begin with as an initial troubleshooting exercise but I'm a bit stumped in terms of how to write a sub-query here that will produce the desired output and eliminate the error.

```
create or replace procedure JUST_ME is

--variables

l_dblink varchar2(100) := 'DB1';
file_handle UTL_FILE.file_type;
v_ts_name varchar2(30);
v_link_name varchar2(10);
v_csv_name varchar2(100);
EST_ONE_ROW_MB varchar2(100) ;
TOTAL_ROW_COUNT NUMBER;
SPACE_REQUIRED NUMBER;
TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB NUMBER;
v_Mv_name varchar2(100);
v_sql1 varchar2(1500);
cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
owner varchar2(100);
table_name varchar2(100);
driver_table varchar2(100);
mandatory_join varchar2(100);
C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT varchar2(100);
v_total_driver_only varchar2(100);
--

begin


SELECT tablename into v_csv_name
FROM BOB01.BOB_new_table_tracker
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from BOB01.BOB_new_table_tracker);

SELECT mv_name into v_Mv_name
FROM BOB01.BOB_new_table_tracker_mv
WHERE
CREATED_AT = (select MAX(CREATED_AT) from BOB01.BOB_new_table_tracker_mv);

select link_name into v_link_name from link_and_mail where mdate = (select max(mdate) from link_and_mail);
select distinct targetschema into v_ts_name from BOB01.MV_BOB_TABLE;

v_sql1 := 'SELECT /*+ monitor parallel (4)*/ a.owner,
                        a.table_name,
                        b.driver_table,
                        b.mandatory_join,
                        sum(c.sum_bytes) TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,
                        (TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB) / (:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) AS "EST_ONE_ROW_MB",
                        (EST_ONE_ROW_MB) * (:TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) AS "SPACE_REQUIRED"
                 FROM dba_tables@DB1 a, '|| v_Mv_name ||' b, MV_PRD_SEG_DATA c
                 WHERE a.table_name IN ( SELECT table_name
                                       FROM MV_BOB_TABLE
                                       WHERE driver_table IS NOT NULL
                                             AND   additional_joins IS NULL
                                     )
                 AND   a.owner IN ( SELECT DISTINCT productionschema FROM MV_BOB_TABLE c  )
                 and a.table_name = b.table_name
                 and a.table_name = c.segment_name
                 group by a.owner,a.table_name,b.driver_table,b.mandatory_join
               ORDER BY table_name';

file_handle := utl_file.fopen('ESTIMATES_CSV', v_csv_name||'_EST_PROC.csv', 'w', 32767);

--
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, 'The below report shows total row counts in PROD');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' for unjoined tables in the BOB document:');
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
utl_file.put_line(file_handle, 'OWNER,TABLE_NAME,MANDATORY_JOIN,TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,EST_ONE_ROW_MB,TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,SPACE_REQUIRED');
--main loop
open cur for v_sql1 using TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;
   loop
      fetch cur into OWNER,TABLE_NAME,MANDATORY_JOIN,TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB,EST_ONE_ROW_MB,TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,SPACE_REQUIRED;--,EST_ONE_ROW_MB;
      exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
      execute immediate' select /*+parallel (4)*/ count(*) from '||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

execute immediate' select /*+monitor parallel (10)*/ count(*) from ' ||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink||' b '||','||
driver_table || '@' || l_dblink||' a ' ||' where ' ||mandatory_join into TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

execute immediate' select /*+monitor parallel (10)*/ count(*) from ' ||owner||'.'||table_name || '@' || l_dblink into C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT;

utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                      OWNER || ',' ||
                      TABLE_NAME || ',' ||
                      TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB || ',' ||
                      TOTAL_ROW_COUNT || ',' ||
                      C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT || ',' || 
                      round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7)|| ',' ||
                      round(round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) * round(TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,0),0)
                      );


v_total_driver_only := v_total_driver_only + round(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB / C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,7) * round(TOTAL_ROW_COUNT,0);

end loop;

UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(file_handle, ' ');
utl_file.put_line(file_handle,
                     'Total Estimated Space Required '|| round(v_total_driver_only,0) ||' MB'
                     );

utl_file.fclose(file_handle);

end JUST_ME;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to use `EST_ONE_ROW_MB` on that way is not possible because its' not defied as column.
replace it by `(TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB) / (:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT)`

```
SELECT /*+ monitor parallel (4)*/ a.owner,
                        a.table_name,
                        b.driver_table,
                        b.mandatory_join,
                        sum(c.sum_bytes) TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB, -- will be the same problem
                        (sum(c.sum_bytes)) / (:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) AS "EST_ONE_ROW_MB",
                        ((sum(c.sum_bytes)) / (:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT)) * (:TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) AS "SPACE_REQUIRED"
...
```

you can do that if you have an Inline View. e.g.

```
select EST_ONE_ROW_MB  * (:TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) AS "SPACE_REQUIRED"
from(
  select (TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB) / (:C_TOTAL_ROW_COUNT) AS "EST_ONE_ROW_MB"
   from ....
)
```

Comment: So, do I need to change the order that the aliases appear in the SQL? Instead of EST_ONE_ROW_MB coming first, from the top down, it needs to be the other way around?

Comment: It isn't the order the aliases appear in your select list, you just can't use them at all in the same level of query (except in the order-by clause). Also notice that `TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB` is declared at the same level, so you can't use that either, and have to replace those references with `sum(c.sum_bytes)` too.

Comment: i see that it will be the same Problem with `TOT_OBJECT_SIZE_MB`. not the order is the problem.  you should use the calculated value  direct not the alias of the column(example 1). or you can  select the values you Need in an inline view and use them for calculated values in your select(example 2).